# Crawler html site with SQL Server (Ole Automation Procedures)

Tags: sql-server, ole

I want to save HTML sites in a table with this query - but it returns Null:

```sql
DECLARE @ResponseTXT NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @obj INT
DECLARE @ValorDeRegreso INT
DECLARE @sUrl NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @hr INT
DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @desc NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @StringRequest NVARCHAR(500)=''

SET @sUrl = 'http://www.myfootballgames.co.uk'    -- as an example

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'--'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', NULL, @StringRequest
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @ResponseTXT OUT

SELECT @ResponseTXT
```

Comment: What if you try getting potential errors using sp_OAGetErrorInfo? Do you get anything?

Comment: sp_OAGetErrorInfo return NULL